# Cockroaches and magnetic fields

Tags: entomology

Aloha, I live in Hawaii working with sharks and their sensitivity to magnetism but here we also have large cockroaches. Has anyone worked with cockroaches and magnetism?  I wonder if placing high magnetic fields near food and anywhere else, would repel cockroaches. Mahalo and aloha.

Comment: Adrianus Kalmijn of the Woods Hole Oceanographic Institute, In 1982, to test whether the Round Stingray (Urolophus halleri ) can orient to magnetic fields, Kalmijn set up weak magnetic fields. When the simulated field was rotated through various degrees, the rays sought food in the 'east' defined by that imposed shift. In field experiments conducted during 1987, Kalmijn set up a ring of electromagnets in shallow waters off Bimini, Bahama Islands, along the known daily route of a Lemon Shark (Negaprion brevirostris).

Comment: the pair of electromagnets which aligned with Earth's magnetic field at that location; when the shark swam by it maintained its course as though nothing had changed. Next day, as the shark swam through the ring of electromagnets, Kalmijn switched the pair of electromagnets which rotated the artificial field 90° to the weaker natural field. The shark altered its course by 90°C in the same direction as the field shift.